# Where do I obtain Windows 7 drivers for the Belkin USB to serial Adapter F5U409?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Where are the new drivers for the [Belkin F5U409 USB to Serial adapter](http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=459431) that will work with Windows 7?

It worked with Windows Vista, but now I am running the 64-bit version of Windows 7 and the Windows Vista drivers will not work....

Answer (score 3):

I have the F5U103v. That is a USB-to-serial adapter too. If you use "Everest home or corporate" software and connect your hardware, although you have a driver error, Everest will indicate to you (in devices/USB devices) the true hardware manufacturer. In this case "Prolific Technology Inc." and not "Belkin".

There is a link for my case and probably yours, but if it doesn't run, use Everest to locate the real manufacturer:

http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/Download-2.asp?ID=17

And click on "PL-2303 USB to Serial Bridge Controller" /software and drivers.
There is support for all Windows OSes, 32 and 64-bit, Windows 7 included.

This same link could help Mac users. Click on "User Manual" for Linux users.

(The "PL-2303" reference is the hardware ID that is located in "Device properties/ Device ID" on Everest software).

Always use this software for locate drivers for your new hardware devices.

**Update:** The site is now down, but through google cache you can still reach the downloads.
Direct links:
[google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ABNe31Rj-S4J:www.prolific.com.tw/eng/downloads.asp%3Fid%3D31+http://www.prolific.com.tw/eng/downloads.asp%3FID%3D31&cd=1&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl)

[windows driver installer](http://www.prolific.com.tw/support/files/%5CIO%20Cable%5CPL-2303%5CDrivers%20-%20Generic%5CWindows%5Callinone%5CPL2303_Prolific_DriverInstaller_v1417.zip) - 
[mac driver installer](http://www.prolific.com.tw/support/files/%5CIO%20Cable%5CPL-2303%5CDrivers%20-%20Generic%5CMacOS%5CMacOS%2010.x%5Cmd_PL2303_MacOSX10.6_dmg_v1.4.0.zip)

Comment: The link appears to be broken (""Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers  ¿ù»~ '80004005'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]³q°T³sµ²¥¢±Ñ /LM/W3SVC/703585378/Root/global.asa, ¦C18.")

Comment: The F5U409 is not a Prolific device.  Since I can't add an answer, see this: http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/how-to-use-a-belkin-f5u409f5u409-cu-usb-to-pda-serial-converter-in-visawindows-7-64bit-mac-osx-10